# UITextView Representable in SwiftUI not respecting bounds for width in ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uitextview

I want to present text in a UITextView using SwiftUI.  I'm using UIViewRepresentable and having issues with the width when it exceeds the bounds of the scrollView.  I would like if to wrap the text but instead it just continues on one long line and the left and right are not visible:

[image]

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var messages = ["here is some long text to show the textView is not wrapping it's content"]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                        ZStack {
                            LazyVStack {
                                ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                                    TextView(text: message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var text: String
     
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
                
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.isEditable = false
        
        textView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        textView.isEditable = false
        
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
        textView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.03137254902, green: 0.4980392157, blue: 0.9960784314, alpha: 1)
        textView.textColor = UIColor.white

        textView.text = text

        return textView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the scrollView.  And either way I would like to know if there is a fix to this?  I tried setting the frame width to geometry.size.width but that did nothing.

Comment: @Asperi I saw your solution for UILabel but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Set the compression resistance priority of your view to `.defaultLow` for the horizontal axis.

```swift
yourView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: It worked gracefully. Thank you, Sivda.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're using a UIRepresentable view. There are a few solutions, simplest of them is to use explicit `.frame()` on top of the UIRepresentable view that is in a SwiftUI view.

e.g. `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` so it only extends as much as screen's width.

Comment: this doesn't work.  and not a good solution as i may want to add other elements in an stack so I don't want to be confined to always using the screen width.  I want it to know it's bounds for width and wrap text with an unlimited height as it's in a scrollView

Comment: Hmm first, you are right, that doesnt work for your case, my apologies. It still should work for most other UIRepresentables. Second, if you are using UIRepresentable, you lose parts of that nice feature of SwiftUI to auto size your views unfortunately. So besically i understand what you awnt but i don't think its possible. i could be wrong.